# Can I expose events from custom views to connect via the Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been experimenting with custom views in the Storyboard. In addition to rendering within `layoutSubviews` and using `didSet` on `@IBOutlet`-enabled properties, I'd like to connect actions similar to how `UIButton` has "Sent Events" in the Connections Inspector.

I assumed it would only involve making a `var action: (() -> ())?` type of property on the `CustomView` and using an `@IB` prefix, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

This is what a `UIButton`'s Connection Inspector looks like.

[image]

And this is my `CustomView`'s Connection Inspector:

[image]

So... is this possible?

Comment: It will appear by default if you subclass UIControl or some subclass an object that is a subclass of UIControl (e.g. UIButton)